# Core Data - Passing Parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I ceated an apllication with empty Xcode template also using Core Data.

Xcode automatically generate the ManagedObjectModel, ManagedObjectCOntex and PersistenStoreCoordinator in my App Delegate.

To keep things clean i want to pass my ManagedObjectContext to my MainVieController and also pass it to my tableViewController (MainViewController is a TabBarViewController that contains TableViewController).

That's the way i did it, but seems like not working:

App Delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  MasterViewController *masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController" bundle:nil];
  [masterViewController setManagedObjectContex:_managedObjectContext];

  [self.window setRootViewController:masterViewController];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}
```

MasterViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  TableIngredientsViewController *tableIngredientVC = [[TableIngredientsViewController alloc]init];
  [tableIngredientVC setManagedObjectContex:_managedObjectContex];
  tableIngredientVC.fetchedResultController = _fetchedResultController;

  TablePizzasViewController *tablePizzaVC = [[TablePizzasViewController alloc]init];
  tablePizzaVC.managedObjectContex =  _managedObjectContex;
  tablePizzaVC.fetchedResultController = _fetchedResultController;

  UINavigationController *ingredientNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableIngredientVC];
  UINavigationController *pizzaNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tablePizzaVC];
 [self setViewControllers:@[pizzaNavController, ingredientNavController]];
}
```

This is error that i get, looks like the managedObjectContext is nill:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'Ingredient''
```

Comment: Is it just that _managedObjectContext hasn't been set at the point that you try and pass it to the masterViewController?

Comment: How can i check that? Is an it the appDelegate that take care of the settings it?

Comment: I think you may be trying to run before you can walk here ...

Answer (score 1):

If memory serves, the Core Data template creates accessor methods for the various objects it needs (including the MOC). You are accessing the backing iVar _managedObjectContext so those accessor methods are not getting called. Try getting it through the accessor method `-managedObjectContext` on the AppDelegate.

Comment: managedObjectContext is nil ... entityForName is a class method

Comment: nope, i tried to do [tableIngredientVC setManagedObjectContex:self.managedObjectContex]; still same error

Comment: any suggest? i'm getting crazy

Comment: @Tim you need to look through the AppDelegate and figure out what sets up the _managedObjectContext. Also, verify your spelling on your view controllers, because the code you keep pasting shows `setManagedObjectContex:` and if you copy & pasted the property name it would be `setManagedObjectContext:`

Comment: everything looks fine, i created an identical app, just used a tableviewcontroller as master, and it worked... core data doesnt work without tableview????

Comment: CoreData most definitely doesn't care about what views you have. It sounds like something got deleted from your AppDelegate - it would probably be easier to move your code to a new project. If that isn't feasible, figure out what methods are responsible for creating and setting the _managedObjectContext in the new project you created and copy those into yours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to use the getter instead of the iVar, as has been mentioned.

Secondly, you can't assume that the MOC has already been set when viewDidLoad is called.

I know that the recommended practice is to hand down your MOC, but this makes things very complicated in most cases. It is, however, needed if you have a more complex setup with parent- and child-contexts.

If you are using only one context in all of your viewControllers, you should just get it from the delegate when you actually need it:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
[...]
- (void) methodThatNeedsToAccessTheMOC {
    AppDelegate *myDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = myDelegate.managedObjectContext;
}
```